# .htaccess rewrite rule to change a path to a query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a project and need some help with rewriting some URLS...

We have a URL such as

```
http://www.example.com/page/a-c/
```

I need it to be interpreted by the server as:

```
http://www.example.com/file.php?source=a-c
```

My .htaccess rewrite skills are not that great!

Answer (score 15):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/? file.php?source=$1
```

Comment: Glad to know this helped someone (as OP didn't respond). Thanks for sharing.